# How do I find absolute URL of an action in Struts 2

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

Suppose I have two actions **details** and **edit**

I need to display in the view that corresponds to details action an link that points to edit action. The problem is that I need this link to be absolute. How can I find the URL of edit action?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the s:url tag and the s:a tag will help?

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/url.html

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/a.html